# java classifieds application

Tags: java

Does anybody know of a good classifieds application written in Java?

**Update**
... by "classifieds application", I mean an application which handles buying and selling, advertisements etc., something like "http://www.ikiclassifieds.com/" but only written in Java.

Comment: Can I ask, what is a classified program?

Comment: I'm guessing classified ads, like you'd see in the newspaper or Craigslist.

Answer (score 1):

Google, as always, would appear to be your friend in this case; "[classified ads java](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=classified+ads+java)" yields various directories which would appear to link to such products, although I can't say I've inspected the results in any great detail.

This is a pretty broad question, soliciting general opinions without providing any kind of real detail relating to what it is you're looking for. You might as well have said, "recommend a blog engine written in Java", for which you could easily have done your own research and found solutions to meet your needs.

More interesting questions might include, "I'm developing a classified ads solution in Java and I'm stuck with this particular aspect", or even, "does anyone have any specific experience with XYZ, the Java-based classified ads system; I'm trying to evaluate it".

Comment: yeah, I'm aware of google, presumably I'm asking here to get some advice on quality, usability etc...

Comment: Yet you haven't explained what criteria are important to you; all you asked was "good", which is a nice, ambiguous adjective.